# Crystal report adding unwanted blank row when exported to excel

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm designing a crystal report using CR11 and exporting it to excel.

On exporting, I have a row of data in Details section, which are perfectly aligned into 1 row of cells, but a blank row is added after each record.

I shifted the Details divider to the uppest i can, but the blank row is still showing.

I have also changed the grid size to 0.026cm as suggested by other guide.

Any advice on what to do?

Comment: Can you do a screenshot of your report and the exported result (with any confidential information redacted) to make it clearer what the problem is?

Comment: try the option `supress empty section`

Comment: As mentioned by Chris, if you upload a screenshot of your report sections as well screen of Section Expert for Details section, we would be able to guide you better.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48013238/1986749) works for me.

(The two questions should probably be marked duplicate, or at least related)