# Crystal reports Excel export empty rows between subreports

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-export

I have a report that only contains a subreport which is executed X times depending on what a USP gives back.

I've formatted everything to be on the same line field-wise and also tried setting margins in Page setup to 0.

In crystal report itself the report looks good and there are no empty spaces. But whenever I export it to Excel I get 2 empty rows between the subreport. The header and footers are supressed as well.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Parent report:

[image: Parent report screenshot]

Sub report:

[image: Sub report screenshot]

Report preview :

[image: Report preview screenshot]

Excel export result:

[image: Excel export screenshot]

Comment: There's a couple of methods to avoid blank lines described in this SO question' thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482374/how-to-eliminate-blank-rows-while-exporting-to-excel

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the export format of 'MS Excel 97-2000 (data only)' try changing it to 'MS Excel 97-2000' and selecting the option of 'Constant column width'.